# Problems with helm-mode (error with helm-subr-native-elisp-p)

Tags: error-handling, emacs

I have noticed that when I enable helm-mode and use some Emacs functions like
`package-install` (or any of the package functions) or `org-insert-link` I get the error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: helm-subr-native-elisp-p
```

I have tried deleting and reinstalling the package to no avail.
Anybody experiencing this issue?

Comment: I also have this issue. No idea as to what's causing it, or how to resolve it.

Comment: @rickerbh I was on Prelude so I reinstalled it from scratch and it got solved.